# OpenLiberty ear postgresql

Tags: jakarta-ee, open-liberty

I want to load postgreSQL jar file from ear archive .
this is my configuration :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <includeLibInApplicationXml>true</includeLibInApplicationXml>
        <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <modules>
            <jarModule>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            </jarModule>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-war</artifactId>
                <uri>/foodpicker.war</uri>
                <!-- Set custom context root -->
                <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and server.xml :

```
<server description="Default Server">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
        <feature>beanValidation-2.0</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
        <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>microProfile-3.3</feature>
        <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
        <feature>jwt-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <library id="project-libs">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/> // <--- not loaded from ear file !!!
    </library>
    <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/jta-datasource" transactional="true">
        <jdbcDriver id="database-driver" libraryRef="project-libs"/>
        <properties databaseName="${database.name}" serverName="${database.hostname}" portNumber="${database.port}"
                    user="${database.username}" password="${database.password}"/>
    </dataSource>
    <basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm"/>
    <httpSession securityIntegrationEnabled="false"/>
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="8080" httpsPort="9443">
        <httpOptions http2="enabled"/>
    </httpEndpoint>
    <webContainer disableXPoweredBy="true"/>
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
</server>
```

this is directory structure of ear file :

```
.
├── foodpicker.war
├── lib
│   └── org.postgresql-postgresql-42.2.12.jar
└── META-INF
    ├── application.xml
    ├── MANIFEST.MF
    └── maven
        └── ir.moke.foodpicker
            └── module-ear
                ├── pom.properties
                └── pom.xml
```

if i change `<fileset>` to absolute path of another directory on filesystem , application load and worked without any problem . but i want to OpenLiberty Application Server load this library from ear file .

How can fix this problem ?

**UPDATE**
finally i configured server.xml to fix this problem :

```
<library id="project-libs">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/jta-datasource" transactional="true">
    <jdbcDriver id="database-driver" libraryRef="project-libs"/>
    <properties databaseName="${database.name}" serverName="${database.hostname}" portNumber="${database.port}"
                user="${database.username}" password="${database.password}"/>
</dataSource>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I got the same problem : all my dependencies in the lib directory inside the ear is not loaded by OpenLiberty...

Answer (score 2):

Server configured data sources in Liberty must load JDBC driver classes from a library that is defined in server configuration via the libraryRef.  This allows the data source, which is backed by a connection pool, to be used across multiple applications if so desired, without needing to be concerned with whether the connection pool is handing out connections from the right class loader to each respective application. So you cannot achieve it in the way that you are configuring it.

However, there is a way (defined by the Java/Jakarta EE spec) to define data sources within the application itself, which can then load JDBC driver classes from the application.

Instead of defining the data source in server.xml, define it in your web component (Servlet)

```
@DataSourceDefinition(name = "java:app/env/jdbc/jta-datasource",
                      className = "org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource",
                      transactional = true,
                      url = "jdbc:postgresql://${database.hostname}:${database.port}/${database.name}",
                      user = "${database.username}",
                      password = "${database.password}")
public class MyServlet ...
```

You can look up the data source as follows,

```
DataSource ds = InitialContext.doLookup("java:app/env/jdbc/jta-datasource");
```

And you can also define resource references to it, just as you would any server-configured data source,

```
@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/jta-datasource-ref", lookup = "java:app/env/jdbc/jta-datasource", shareable = true)
DataSource jtaDataSource;
```

Comment: My problem is , Application Server don't load jdbc jar file from ear archive .

Comment: How can force Liberty application server to load jdbc driver from lib directory inside ear archive ?

Comment: The only way to get a Liberty data source to load a JDBC driver from the application archive is to switch to application-defined data source `@DataSourceDefinition` in a web component (or `data-source` in a deployment descriptor if you prefer), as shown in my example above.  In this case, you remove the `dataSource` and `jdbcDriver` elements from server.xml because server.xml data sources simply cannot load from application classes per Liberty architecture, and you define them in the application instead, as shown.

Answer (score 0):

We use postgres with openliberty.
**Our server.xml has the following entry:**
`

```
<dataSource id="postgresds" jndiName="jdbc/postgresds"
                isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED"
                type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"
                transactional="true" supplementalJDBCTrace="true">
    <jdbcDriver javax.sql.XADataSource="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource"
   javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource"
                    libraryRef="global">
        </jdbcDriver>
        <properties serverName="localhost" currentSchema="${datasource.schema}" portNumber="5532"
                    databaseName="${datasource.dbname}"
                    user="postgres" password="postgres"
                    loggerLevel="TRACE" logServerErrorDetail="true"
                    ssl="false"/>
</dataSource>
```

`

**Project pom:**
`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>42.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

`

**persistence.xml:**
`

```
<properties>   
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5532/postgres"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
</properties>
```

`